# XAML - How do I align controls next to each other in a StackPanel

Tags: wpf, xaml

I've been trying to align the controls in the following code next to each other. But it doesn't seem to work. First I had it without the StackPanel but then I couldn't really align my Controls properly.

Here is my code:

```xml
<StackPanel x:Name="doelenContentPanel" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
    <TextBlock x:Name="txtBOmzet" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Omzet:  " Margin="10,58,-10,-58" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
    <TextBox x:Name="txtbOmzet" Margin="82,58,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="txtBOmzetMaand" Margin="151,58,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Maand" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Got it!
I added the `Orientation="Horizontal"` property to the `StackPanel`. However, this only aligns the content of this specific panel. If, for example, you want to have 2 `StackPanel` vertically aligned and then have the content of these 2 panels horizontally aligned, you have to do this:

```
<StackPanel x:Name="contentWrapper" Orientation="Vertical">
    <StackPanel x:Name="doelenContentPanel" Orientation="Horizontal">
    <TextBlock x:Name="txtBOmzet" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Omzet:  "  />
    <TextBox x:Name="txtbOmzet" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" />
    <TextBlock x:Name="txtBOmzetMaand" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Maand" />
</StackPanel>
<StackPanel x:Name="secondPanel" Orientation="Horizontal">
    *this looks familiar to the first panel*
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: something smells about that inner StackPanel, without closing element . . .

Answer (score 13):

First, don't use the hardcoded `Margin` property and second remove the `HorizontalAlignment` from each control. 
Now to align the control next to each other, set the Orientation property of `StackPanel`

```
<StackPanel x:Name="doelenContentPanel" Orientation="Horizontal">
  <TextBlock x:Name="txtBOmzet" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Omzet:  "  />
  <TextBox x:Name="txtbOmzet" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" />
  <TextBlock x:Name="txtBOmzetMaand" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Maand" />
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Well the controls are centered but the height of the textbox is takes up like 100% of the page's height

Comment: Then you should be grid's row and column definitions to define height and width of child controls. After that set the Grid.Row attached property on StackPanel

Comment: Can you give an example?